# Expect script - sending filename with a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, expect

I want to create a script so that I copy the newest file from an SFTP server, for that I have created a script that gets the name and put the name in a file.

Now I want to create another script to download the newest file which I have the name, but I am struggling with passing the content of my file to a variable and then downloading that file.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set name "testnamefromfile"

expect << 'EOS'
 spawn sftp -P 2222 admin@172.22.44.37:/var/log/datarecord
 expect "admin@172.22.44.37's password:"
 send "admin\n"
 expect "sftp>"
 send "get $name\r"
 expect "sftp>"
 send "bye\n"
EOS
```

This is my script. How can I assign the content of the file to the `$name` variable? And how to download that file?

When I run this script it throws out below error:

```
sftp> can't read "name": no such variable
    while executing
"send "get $name\r""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script you have

```
   set name "testnamefromfile"
```

but this sets the variable `$1` to `name` and the variable `$2` to `testnamefromfile`.

Then you have

```
expect << 'EOS'
```

As `'EOS'` is quoted no variable substitution will take place in the "heredoc".

The following may work better (untested, also changed \n to \r when sending password).

```
#!/bin/sh

name="testnamefromfile"

expect << EOS
 spawn sftp -P 2222 admin@172.22.44.37:/var/log/datarecord
 expect "admin@172.22.44.37's password:"
 send "admin\r"
 expect "sftp>"
 send "get $name\r"
 expect "sftp>"
 send "bye\n"
EOS
```

Comment: thank you so much dear icarus, it worked. 
Kind Regards,

Comment: \n and \r both accomplish "hitting enter", but \r is more idiomatic. After sending bye, one should `expect eof` to allow the connection to close gracefully.

Comment: @HediHadwan if you found the answer useful, please consider [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) so that others facing a similar problem may find it more easily.